# ocamlfind query ... terminated with error code 2

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I am trying to install the ocaml package from this GitHub:

```
https://github.com/jfeser/L2
```

On Linux Ubuntu 14.04.
I've installed ocaml and relevant tools (I think) with:

```
sudo apt-get install ocaml
sudo apt-get install opam
```

But when I'm trying to run the ocaml setup,
I get the error message:

```
ocamlfind: Package `core' not found W: Field 'pkg_core' is not set:
Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlfind' query -format %d core > '/tmp/oasis-
c4f09c.txt'' terminated with error code 2
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks Mars, opam install core (and other packages) solved this problem.
However, I'm now facing this:

```
ocaml setup.ml -build 
W: Cannot find source file matching module 'l2' in library l2.
W: Use InterfacePatterns or ImplementationPatterns to define this file 
with feature "source_patterns".
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ /home/oren/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamldep -pp 'ppx-jane -dump-
ast' -predicates ppx_driver -package yojson -package hashcons -package 
core_extended -package core -modules src/l2-lib/ast.ml > src/l2-
lib/ast.ml.depends
sh: 1: ppx-jane: not found
Preprocessing error on file src/l2-lib/ast.ml
Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: ppx-jane -dump-ast 'src/l2-lib/ast.ml' > 
/tmp/ocamlpp266286

Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 
00:00:00.
E: Failure("Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlbuild' src/l2-lib/l2.cma src/l2-
lib/l2.cmxa src/l2-lib/l2.a src/l2-lib/l2.cmxs src/l2-cli/l2.native 
src/l2-cli/l2.byte src/l2-tests/tests.native -use-ocamlfind -plugin-
tags 'package(ppx_driver.ocamlbuild)' -j 8 -tag debug' terminated with 
error code 10")
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: This might be referring to the Core package (from Jane Street): https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/core .  Try running `opam update` and then `opam install core` from a command line.  This will take several minutes.  If you haven't already done so, you also might want to make sure you have the latest production release of OCaml.  This can be done with opam as well.

Comment: Also, it looks like jfeser may have set up L2 to be an opam package, but it's not listed in the opam package list https://opam.ocaml.org/packages.  Maybe he would be willing to install it for downloading via opam.  This should mean that all dependencies would be installed automatically when one runs `opam install l2`.

Comment: I think you should just open a bug report directly with that package